# New site proposal specifically for problem solving in Physics on Area 51

Tags: discussion, support

**"Physics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for active researchers, academics and students of physics."**

At present Physics Stack Exchange is more inclined towards answering specific conceptual questions in Physics and not really meant for problem solving at the High School/Undergraduate/Graduate level. Check-my-work problems ( even if they contain the OP's efforts, are discouraged most of the times ). Moreover, we do not have any quality site on the Internet related to problem solving techniques in Physics ( specifically numerical problems ).

I remember that in my high school days I used to end up tearing my hairs even after spending hours on a particular numerical problem ( and my teachers weren't always available to discuss the solutions as they would quite busy ) . Several times I would have to wait weeks before I could get someone to explain me where I was going wrong during solving the numerical problem. So, I wish to make a site for students and physics enthusiasts so that they get a platform to discuss their methods of solving problems in Physics. Of course, homework questions with no effort is discouraged.

[I proposed this site here on on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/103955/physics-problem-solving/103962) and if you wish you can support the site by following it. Feel free to give suggestions regarding the new site proposal in comments or in form of answers.

I also feel that this could be a solution to the constant debate whether particular problem-solving question belongs to Physics Stack Exchange or not.
Then Physics Stack Exchange can go back to its original ideal - that is to serve as a knowledge resource for researchers and academicians.

Comment: Best of luck with your proposal, but you should know that there have been similar attempts in the past and they have struggled to recruit a sufficient critical mass of people that can answer such questions.

Comment: Oct 29, 2016: [Proposal closed as a duplicate on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/103955/physics-problem-solving).

Comment: In an unexpected turn we've been made an offer to host the site from Physics Overflow. Though whether this comes to anything we'll have to wait and see.

Comment: @JohnRennie we do not run our own server, so we can not offer hosting as such. But hosting, for example on [one.com](https://www.one.com/de/) where also PhysicsOverflow lives, dose not cost the world. What we can do is offer (at first) a basic version of our software (including LaTex, the ability to import (for example closed) questions, regain access to their imported accounts for SE users who want to join the project. What is needed to start it is get hosting and a volunteer superadmin who is willing to install the software in accordance with the instructions of our system developper.

Comment: @Dilaton In that case, could you write a post in detail about what steps we should follow ? You can use the Meta for that.

Comment: @S007 more details about the steps needed are given in the lower part of [this](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/17130/a-beginners-complementation-to-physicsoverflow?show=17130#q17130) post (it was about a slightly diffrent idea for a new site), starting with the title "How can I help?". Maybe an important thing to clarify is also that the new community would have to make and agree on their own policies and rules and implement them by their own moderators and high rep users.

Comment: Please don't undertake destructive edits like this. Add banners above or below the previous content, if you want to, but keep the original post.

Answer (score 8):

Well, a whole lot of things have happened, but in a nutshell:

1. Our proposal was closed as a duplicate.
2. We got an offer from physics overflow to host the site.
3. [Mew](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/12350/mew) is building the site by hand.

We want the relations between our new site, Physics Problems Q&A, and Physics.SE to be friendly. Hopefully, once our site is firmly established, we can establish some sort of protocol for migrating questions between sites, or at the very least recommending the other site to users. We certainly do not want a relationship like that between Physics Overflow and Physics.SE. We would be glad to welcome any users to our site; please see our [first draft of our scope and guidelines](http://physicsproblems.nfshost.com/?qa=116/scope-%26-guidelines) to know what we expect. Moderators on the site are myself, S007, and Mew (username Einstein on the new site).

Our site is coming along quite well although there are still improvements to be made, both in the construction of the site and in the general guidelines. If you have any questions, the chatroom on the new site is still under construction, so please ping one of us at [this stack exchange chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47874/physics-problem-solving).

Thank you!

Comment: @SirJMP, it is indeed independent of the SE network, though we do want collaboration between our site and SE. Come on over, we'd be glad to have you!

Comment: When will the site going to be launched