# An attempt at a homework-closure statistic and a bit of input concerning the ongoing policy debate

Tags: discussion

### Summary

I made a week-long list of all the questions closed due to the homework flag and tried to gauge whether they were showing any effort at all. This idea came up during a chat session when we were talking about the new physics Q&A site proposal and our homework policy. The hope is to give a few examples of questions that are discussion-worthy (and of questions that are definitely not) and to obtain a feeling for the relative amount of each of those.

---

### Introduction

During the chat session of November the first, the question of the homework policy (reformulation) came up again, especially with reference to the [turned down new site proposal on SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9303/new-site-proposal-specifically-for-problem-solving-in-physics-on-area-51) and [the newly opened help website](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9320/physics-problem-solving-site). This led us to consider what kind of questions we would like to be answered there (but not here) and in what way this could affect this site here. (All quotes are from the [chat protocol](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/conversation/chat-session-11-1-16).)

> David Z: I think it would be useful to have some examples of questions that would be considered good and on topic at the hypothetical new site, from those who are involved in setting it up.
>   Better yet, to have examples of questions which would be on topic there and off topic here.

After a bit of searching I was not able to find many well written questions closed due to the homework reason and it was not only me:

> John Rennie :Having gone through a few pages of the search I posted above it's striking how few questions do show significant effort by the OP. The vast majority just post the question and ask how do I do this?

Further down the conversation I asked whether the amount of questions which really showed effort but still get closed under the current site policy is that substantial at all. Questions of this form would e.g. be of the "did I do something wrong?"-kind or "I am stuck at this point in my solution attempt"-kind. David wanted to take that to the meta to discuss, but I wanted to collect a bit of data first.

### Method

From the 1st of November after the chat session until the 8th of November I regularly visited [this site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20closed%3ayes) of newly closed questions on Physics SE, went through the last 24h and singled out all questions closed for homework reasons. I recorded them and for each of them I gave an estimate whether they could - maybe with a small bit of editing - be made into nice questions that do not fit in with our policy but *do* show effort at solution by the OP. I realise that a) questions get deleted sometimes rather quickly, so I might have easily missed some, b) this is all a bit subjective and c) a week is not that much time. But still, to me it seems like it will be nice to have a bit of a data-based feeling for what we are actually talking about when we are talking about redoing the homework policy.

### Results

From 87 questions that I recorded as closed due to homework-reasons, I would grade 64 as showing no effort at all. This is 74% of the questions closed for that reason, but still - 23 questions remain. This surprised me, to be honest, and in my mind it is a good reason to actually build up an alternative site for good, well-written "homework"-questions.
I would be happy about other people doing the same to obtain a bit more data :D I also hope this helps us to decide better when considering how and whether to modify the homework policy.

### Appendix - List and Links of Questions

Questions I gauged as "showing effort" or "being salvagable through small edits"
[How to prove that internal energy for a system whose temperature is negative is bounded between 1/2 and 1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290321/how-to-prove-that-internal-energy-for-a-system-whose-temperature-is-negative-is) ([png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuuH0.png))
[Molecular simulation of ideal gas- descriptive statistical analysis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290173/molecular-simulation-of-ideal-gas-descriptive-statistical-analysis)  ([png 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz2e1.png), [png 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixTss.png))
[Question about Galilean relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290362/question-about-galilean-relativity)
[Find the charges on each Capacitor after a long time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290636/find-the-charges-on-each-capacitor-after-a-long-time)  ([png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si8bJ.png))
[Work and kinetic energy on an incline?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290728/work-and-kinetic-energy-on-an-incline)
[A neutron (rest mass 940MeV/c 2 ) is measured in the lab to have energy 2GeV](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290729/a-neutron-rest-mass-940mev-c-2-is-measured-in-the-lab-to-have-energy-2gev)
[work and change of kenetic energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290987/work-and-change-of-kenetic-energy)
[A block is pushed onto a conveyor belt](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290984/a-block-is-pushed-onto-a-conveyor-belt)  ([png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSDFI.png))
[Lagrangian for double Atwood machine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290922/lagrangian-for-double-atwood-machine)  ([png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGfwu.png))
[Find the acceleration for a given mass and velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291081/find-the-acceleration-for-a-given-mass-and-velocity)  ([png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JkA9.png))
[Pully and Inclined Ramp](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291059/pully-and-inclined-ramp)
[Uncertainty in the angle by using Heisenberg's uncertainty principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291053/uncertainty-in-the-angle-by-using-heisenbergs-uncertainty-principle)
[Electric Field at Centre of Hemispherical Cup](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291022/electric-field-at-centre-of-hemispherical-cup)  ([png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaVyY.png))
[Oscillation of charge problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291147/oscillation-of-charge-problem)  ([png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6dS0.png))
[Find the time of movement if the maximal height is equal to the distance of fall](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291133/find-the-time-of-movement-if-the-maximal-height-is-equal-to-the-distance-of-fall)  ([png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjIYQ.png))
[Two flashes of light for two observers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291265/two-flashes-of-light-for-two-observers)  ([png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSXZZ.png))
[Finding the period of a system in simple harmonic motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291253/finding-the-period-of-a-system-in-simple-harmonic-motion)
[How to find the amount of work done against gravity from an object moving diagonally?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291248/how-to-find-the-amount-of-work-done-against-gravity-from-an-object-moving-diagon)
[Propeller torque on the shaft when rotational speed and Thrust is given](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291171/propeller-torque-on-the-shaft-when-rotational-speed-and-thrust-is-given)  ([png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkt61.png))
[Moment of inertia, lab exercise](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291377/moment-of-inertia-lab-exercise)  ([png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vticH.png))
[Time needed for photon to reach the surface of a white dwarf](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291294/time-needed-for-photon-to-reach-the-surface-of-a-white-dwarf) 
[Energy conservation … Basic qustion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291266/energy-conservation-basic-qustion)  ([png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ3RW.png))
[Quantitative Study of Mirage](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291535/quantitative-study-of-mirage)
Questions I gauged as "no effort shown"
[Linear motion problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290130/linear-motion-problem)
[Magnitude of the magnetic field of an electron moving with 0.99c?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290129/magnitude-of-the-magnetic-field-of-an-electron-moving-with-0-99c)
[What is expected from switch S?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290098/what-is-expected-from-switch-s)
[Minimum velocity for a charged particle to go through all the magnetic field's zone](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290075/minimum-velocity-for-a-charged-particle-to-go-through-all-the-magnetic-fields-z)
[conservation of momentum and energy to find speed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290051/conservation-of-momentum-and-energy-to-find-speed)
[Find the flux of a charge through a finite plane](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290032/find-the-flux-of-a-charge-through-a-finite-plane)
[Statistical physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290031/statistical-physics)
[Calculate the velocity of the particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290334/calculate-the-velocity-of-the-particle)
[a question of pulley and monkey](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290337/a-question-of-pulley-and-monkey)
[A projectile question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290344/a-projectile-question)
[Classical Action](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290236/classical-action)
[Oliver has a mass of 70.5kg and can throw a 542.0g rock with a speed of 10.4m/s. What would Oliver's recoil speed be if he were on an icy surface?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290285/oliver-has-a-mass-of-70-5kg-and-can-throw-a-542-0g-rock-with-a-speed-of-10-4m-s)
[Parachutist jumps out of plane - Find work (parachute)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290286/parachutist-jumps-out-of-plane-find-work-parachute)
[Damped harmonic oscillator differential equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290292/damped-harmonic-oscillator-differential-equation)
[A question of projectile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290325/a-question-of-projectile)
[How do I find distance if I have acceleration and time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290232/how-do-i-find-distance-if-i-have-acceleration-and-time)
[Calculate the equivalent resistance seen from the E6 generator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290228/calculate-the-equivalent-resistance-seen-from-the-e6-generator)
[Eigenvalues of Hamiltonian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290218/eigenvalues-of-hamiltonian)
[Deriving Bernoulli's equation from Navier-Stokes equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290175/deriving-bernoullis-equation-from-navier-stokes-equation)
[state the different levels of stress and strain in a rigid body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290361/state-the-different-levels-of-stress-and-strain-in-a-rigid-body)
[Bosonic and Fermionic harmonic oscillators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290365/bosonic-and-fermionic-harmonic-oscillators)
[Mechanics of system of particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290372/mechanics-of-system-of-particles)
[Electric field between three parallel plates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290480/electric-field-between-three-parallel-plates)
[From special relativity to general relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290461/from-special-relativity-to-general-relativity)
[How to prove the following Dirac matrices identity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290434/how-to-prove-the-following-dirac-matrices-identity)
[angular spread in the angle of refraction of the beam](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290418/angular-spread-in-the-angle-of-refraction-of-the-beam)
[minimum area of the disc to collect all light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290415/minimum-area-of-the-disc-to-collect-all-light)
[Nutcracker problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290394/nutcracker-problem)
[Quantum Physics Easy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290667/quantum-physics-easy)
[By how much does the image move when the object is moved by 10cm in the given lens configuration?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290645/by-how-much-does-the-image-move-when-the-object-is-moved-by-10cm-in-the-given-le)
[What is the acceleration of point D and E when F = 125N?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290644/what-is-the-acceleration-of-point-d-and-e-when-f-125n)
[Examination Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290641/examination-question)
[How do I prove that a disk charge resembles a point charge if its radius shrinks to 0?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290573/how-do-i-prove-that-a-disk-charge-resembles-a-point-charge-if-its-radius-shrinks) 
[How does the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor vary as the length of the dielectric inside it changes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290546/how-does-the-capacitance-of-a-parallel-plate-capacitor-vary-as-the-length-of-the)
[How do I express this. If I use Lorenz transform, It depends on mc2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290538/how-do-i-express-this-if-i-use-lorenz-transform-it-depends-on-mc2)
[moving object - vectors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290687/moving-object-vectors)
[The classical theory of fields - Landau book problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290710/the-classical-theory-of-fields-landau-book-problem)
[Calculating Magnitude of Force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290837/calculating-magnitude-of-force)
[What are the relationships between radius, velocity and centripetal force on an object?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290739/what-are-the-relationships-between-radius-velocity-and-centripetal-force-on-an)
[Electrons during radioactive decay](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291006/electrons-during-radioactive-decay)
[Mechanics problem and confusion regarding reference frame calculation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290965/mechanics-problem-and-confusion-regarding-reference-frame-calculation)
[An object that is not accelerating or decelerating has zero net force acting on it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290955/an-object-that-is-not-accelerating-or-decelerating-has-zero-net-force-acting-on)
[Confusion on conservation of angular momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290938/confusion-on-conservation-of-angular-momentum)
[Rotational Imbalance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290930/rotational-imbalance)
[Does a current-carrying solenoid exert force on itself](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291079/does-a-current-carrying-solenoid-exert-force-on-itself) 
[Classical Mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291050/classical-mechanics)
[do you know why Q2 has negative sign?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291044/do-you-know-why-q2-has-negative-sign)
[Frame of reference and work done by pseudo force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291032/frame-of-reference-and-work-done-by-pseudo-force)
[Induced current in a circular loop](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291029/induced-current-in-a-circular-loop)
[X and Y collide, find angle of Y](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291023/x-and-y-collide-find-angle-of-y)
[Related to torque generated, to find input and output torque](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291117/related-to-torque-generated-to-find-input-and-output-torque)
[moment of inertia in beam](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291116/moment-of-inertia-in-beam)
[Converting from rectangular to polar and vice-versa](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291108/converting-from-rectangular-to-polar-and-vice-versa) 
[What are **Energy levels, Sublevels, and Orbitals**?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291096/what-are-energy-levels-sublevels-and-orbitals)
[Boundary layer flow directed radially towards a sink](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291230/boundary-layer-flow-directed-radially-towards-a-sink)
[Writing Fokker Planck equation for levy walker in a given potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291209/writing-fokker-planck-equation-for-levy-walker-in-a-given-potential)
[What is the kinetic energy possessed by a battle tank belt whose mass is m if the tank is moving with a constant velocity v?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291174/what-is-the-kinetic-energy-possessed-by-a-battle-tank-belt-whose-mass-is-m-if-th)
[Simple Harmonic Motion Question With Explanation Please!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291459/simple-harmonic-motion-question-with-explanation-please) 
[Find the height and the instant velocity of a geostationary satellite](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291444/find-the-height-and-the-instant-velocity-of-a-geostationary-satellite)
[What are the image formations at different positions for plano convex and plano concave lenses?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291412/what-are-the-image-formations-at-different-positions-for-plano-convex-and-plano) 
[Moment of inertia of semicircular disc](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291367/moment-of-inertia-of-semicircular-disc)
[Poincare algebra](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291354/poincare-algebra)
[Finding gravitational force on a body of unit mass by other three bodies](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291582/finding-gravitational-force-on-a-body-of-unit-mass-by-other-three-bodies)
[Rotational mech](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/291548/rotational-mech)

Comment: first of all, kudos on the effort! As you say, there are around 23 good hw questions per week. From [area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics),  "10 questions per day on average is a healthy beta, 5 questions or fewer per day needs some work.". Read this as you want, but 23 a week doesn't seem too good, right?

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem too good for launching another SE site, point taken. It does seem promising for a small side project if it was allowed to send people there. On the other hand, maybe it should be taken as a sign that we should just be more lenient (I am totally unsure about the average number of questions/week here) because it is a small number (even though it might grow if we start doing that)? In any case - there is a small demand.

Comment: We get between 550 and 750 questions per week, fluctuating over the year (>20k (?) users can view such data [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/site-analytics)).

Comment: 25k rep is needed to see @ACuriousMind's link

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, good point, however, I might just point out that this is *without homework questions being allowed*. If they were allowed, even encouraged, then surely there would be more. If this many good questions are coming in as is, I think it is fair to say that a number close to a good amount could possibly come in with the homework policy encouraged.

Comment: For reference, [here's](http://physics.qandaexchange.com/?qa=questions) our new questions page (on Physics Problems Q&A) and the closed/open questions should hopefully give an idea of what we allow and don't allow.

Comment: So what is your question here? Perhaps this question should be closed because it is "unclear what you are asking"!

Comment: @heather yes, I agree with that.

Comment: I have put in an answer, but I take sammy gerbil's point that you might make the actual question more prominent.

Comment: "I would be happy about other people doing the same to obtain a bit more data". I doubt anyone will feel inclined to do so, when every question listed as "no effort" is deleted soon after, making it impossible to compare, or check whether any of the answers were useful.