# Can a new physical science SE for beginners in physics be created?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, homework-and-exercises, migration

Can a simple physics SE be designed for people who have little or no training who are enthusiasts none the less? That way moderators can instant migrate lessor questions there instead of instant close? Consisting of answers and questions for everyone to understand it would provide a new Physics093.beta for beginners. There is plenty of places to learn but not in the SE format that many prefer including myself.

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/9369/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/391/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic updated my question. How can I help create this?

Comment: Probably also related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1576/, http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7223/

Comment: "Pysics SE 093"? "lessor questions"? "Consisting Lamond"? Please take the time to proofread your posts, I have no idea what the significance of 093 here is supposed to be or what a "Lamond" is.

Comment: @ACuriousMind 093  is like a high school level class in collage to get you ready for 101 level class. Also fixed the Lamond

Comment: So... you want a site where you don't need to spend any effort on your questions, but still get top-notch answers?

Comment: "There is plenty of places to learn"... Have you given them a try?

Answer (score 8):

Such a question is not in scope for this particular Meta site, but can be proposed over at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), which is where Stack Exchange sites are proposed.

Note that there have been similar proposals (a short list among others)

- [Should we have a Popular Physics SE?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5697/25301)
- [New site proposal specifically for problem solving in Physics on Area 51](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9303/new-site-proposal-specifically-for-problem-solving-in-physics-on-area-51)
- [How about a "physics problems" stack exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/931/how-about-a-physics-problems-stack-exchange)

None of these have been successful in garnering much interest (i.e., critical mass interest to actually support a site). I sincerely doubt your latest attempt would be any more successful.

There is also [Heather & Mew's Physics Problem site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9320/physics-problem-solving-site), but note that (a) it is *not* an SE site and (b) I have no idea what is going on there.

Comment: FWIW, we do have standards for our questions (effort needs to be shown being a big one) though how well they are being enforced is up in the air.

Answer (score 7):

If someone is *genuinely* interested in learning physics, there are plenty of resources on the web that are infinitely better for learning than the SE question/answer format. This is likely the reason that previous attempts to start a "popular physics" SE haven't had much interest.

The excellent [Khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics) courses are a great starting point, as is Wikipedia, as well as the dozens of channels on YouTube that will walk you through anything you'd like to learn. After that, there's the entire catalog of [MIT OpenCourseWare](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/) that contains astounding amounts of material, plus exams with solutions.

There's simply no reason to rehash elementary concepts on SE, when they're so readily accessible with the simplest web search.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that would work out, Jen.

If simple questions are migrated to another site, the experts will not go there to answer them. Users who want to answer questions will stay here, especially the experts who want to find difficult, interesting questions to tackle.

The users whose questions have been migrated will not get the high-quality answers which they come here for. They will only get a few low-quality answers, because most users of that site will be looking for answers, and will not be able to provide good answers anyway. They will be disappointed and will not keep using the other site.

The effect of migrating low-level problems will work out just the same as when they are closed on Physics SE.

The reason users like you stay here is probably because they value the feedback they get from a broad community of physicists. Sometimes your questions are closed quickly, but even if that happens you still get a lot of feedback from comments, which is valuable even when it is critical. So you put up with the difficulties because they are outweighed by the advantages.